# How to fix "A virtual path is expected" from HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.web

In a custom class derived from System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult, I have the following line of code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(myUrl, true);
```

In most situations, this works fine. But occasionally, it fails with the error:

```
Uncaught error in MVC Controller
ArgumentException: Invalid path for child request 'http://[...]'. A virtual path is expected.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How are you constructing the url (myUrl in this case) ?

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth In my app, it was coming from a configuration option, which by default had a value of a relative path, but could be overridden by specific users to have an absolute URL, which is what turned out to be the condition where the error would occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the last part of the error message says, the problem is the URL argument being passed to the `TransferRequest` method.

The method expects a relative path, not an absolute URL including a domain. For example, this argument is ok:

```
"/Search.aspx"
```

This argument would cause the error:

```
"http://example.com/Search.aspx"
```